# handle stderr with another script

Tags: bash, stderr

I have a script (eg. compute.sh) that does something on my Ubuntu 16.04 and may end with error, let's say:

```
[compute.sh]

#!/bin/bash

...

MISCELLANEOUS OPERATIONS

...

[if error occours]
echo "Error 55a" >&2;
exit 1;

...

echo "Execution ok";
exit 0;
```

and another script that handles errors (eg. error_handler.sh)

```
[error_handler.sh]

error=$(cat)

for i in "$@"
do
case $i in
    -u=*|--user=*)
    username="${i#*=}"
    shift
    ;;
    -t=*|--task=*)
    task="${i#*=}"
    shift
    ;;
esac
done

...

SENDS ERROR REPORTING THROUGH AN API LISTENING REMOTELY

...
```

I'd like to execute compute.sh, redirecting its stderr to error_handler.sh in order to notify my API system the error occourred

if I try this test:

```
user@ubuntu: echo "test message" | ./error_handler.sh --user=dude --task="simple task"
```

my error_handler.sh script takes the string "test message" and correctly handles it

how can I redirect only the stderr output to my error_handler.sh script?

EDIT: as sometimes compute.sh may fail without an error message (just by doing exit 1;) I'm not sure if error=$(cat) it's the right way to catch the error message in error_handler.sh. Any other option?

EDIT2: the task may be executed in a crontab, so I need to do all in the same command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is create a named pipe to act as the buffer between the two.

```
mkfifo errors           # "errors" is an arbitrary file name
compute.sh 2> errors &  # Run in the background
error_handler.sh < errors
```

As one line:

```
mkfifo errors; compute.sh 2> errors & error_handler.sh
```

Now the two processes run concurrently, and `error_handler.sh` can read from `errors` as `compute.sh` writes to it. The buffer is of bounded size, so `compute.sh` will automatically block if it gets full. Once `error_handler.sh` consumes some input, `compute.sh` will automatically resume. As long as errors aren't produced too quickly (i.e., faster than `error_handler.sh` can process them), `compute.sh` will run as if the buffer were unbounded.

If the buffer is ever emptied, `error_handler.sh` will block until either more input is available, or until `compute.sh` closes its end of the pipe by exiting.

---

Regular pipeline syntax `foo | bar` creates an anonymous pipe (or unnamed pipe), and it is just a shortcut for

```
mkfifo tmp
foo > tmp &
bar < tmp
```

but limits you to connecting standard output of one command to standard input of another. Using other file descriptors requires contorted redirections. Using named pipes is slightly longer to type, but can be *much* clearer to read.

Comment: it may be a solution, but I need to execute all in the same command (it's a crontab executed task)

Comment: The "command" in `cron` is just a string that gets passed to `sh -c`; it can consist of multiple commands separated by `;`, `&`, etc.